# Middle English “Whan that” vs “Whan”

Tags: phrase-usage, that, middle-english, coordinating-conjunctions

> **whan**   pronoun
> Definitions (Senses and Subsenses) **whom**
> <sub>[MED online](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED52414)  University of Michigan</sub>

How does one construe “that” in the phrase “Whan that”? This seems to be the normal construction in ME, but sometimes “Whan” occurs without an accompanying “that”, as when Chaucer begins

> “Whan that Aprille with his showres soote”

only to continue

> “Whan Zephyrus eek with his sweete breeth”.

Please don’t say it’s all down to the meter. I am trying to understand what “that” meant to contemporary speakers both semantically and syntactically. I have the feeling I may be missing something that ought to be obvious.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question can be found in the link I posted. Usage/meaning N.6

Comment: Thank you. I assume you mean usage 5. Perhaps more helpful to me is the introduction to the entry which outlines relationship of whanne to hwa. (Spellcheck plays havoc with all this of course.)

Comment: Yes, for some reason I misread it; it's the last note. The intro is interesting and a little intimidating for people who have never studied Middle English such as myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaucer's *that* in *whan that* is a complementizer for tensed clauses,
just as it is today for tensed complement clauses:

- *I think **that** I shall never see a poem.*
- *The story **that** Putin will sing at La Scala is probably not true.*

It also occurs in restrictive (but not non-restrictive) relative clauses, but there it has changed into another possible relative pronoun with no special meaning, unlike *wh*-words, which(*who) are restricted in reference and use. Relative pronouns that are not the subject of the relative clause are deletable, and there are lots of odd wrinkles:

- *the man **that**/who saw you; the man (**that**/who/whom) you saw; the man you saw* (restrictive)
- *the boy, who was sitting on the bike;* **the boy, **that** was sitting on the bike,* (non-restrictive)
- *the reason (**that**/why) he did it; the way (**that**) he did it;* **the way how he did it*

But Chaucer used it to mark a tensed adverb clause, and that's not standard English any more. But there are local dialects that still have it, like the North Carolina rural accent that Andy Griffith uses in [his routine about football](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNxLxTZHKM8). Listen at 12 seconds or so from the start for

- ***before that we set up the tent***

which is Chaucer's *that*, marking  an adverb clause as tensed.

Comment: Can I point out that the tensed clause *that* complements extends into the next lines of the poem? “Whan that *Aprill with his shoures soote
The droghte of March hath perced to the roote,
And bathed every veyne in switch licour
Of which vertu engendred is the flour.*

Comment: Cf.  "Her olde father woll yet make her dine/ **Ere that she go**, God yeve his herte pine". *Troilus and Creseide*, Book V.

Comment: I never had a problem with the meaning though I had not remembered is as an idiom that had persisted as late as Shakespeare. Rather I cdntthat  But I didn’t remember it as   A feature

Answer (score 0):

The OED has an entry on this obsolete use that seems to be periphrastic but idiomatic:

> **That** (conj.)
>
> **7. b. Added** to relative or interrogative pronouns and adjectives (who, which, what, etc.) and **to relative conjunctions (when, where,
> how, why, etc.). †Also added to the demonstrative adverbs then, there,
> etc., when used as relatives (obsolete).** Now regional or archaic.
>
> lOE   Writ of Edward the Confessor (Sawyer 1098) in F. E. Harmer
> Anglo-Saxon Writs (1952) 219   *Ælce mannum gebyreð swyðe rihte ure
> drihten God luuien..& ælmesdæden georne befellen þurh hwan þæt he of
> synbænden hine selfne mote alynian.*
>
> c1405  (▸c1395)    G. Chaucer Canon's Yeoman's Tale (Ellesmere) (1875)
> l. 570   *And in myn herte to wondren I bigan What þat he was.*
>
> a1413  (▸c1385)    G. Chaucer Troilus & Criseyde (Pierpont Morgan)
> (1881) ii. l. 36   *Euery wyght whiche that to rome went.*
>
> a1616   W. Shakespeare Julius Caesar (1623) iii. ii. 92   *When that
> the poore haue cry'de, Cæsar hath wept.*
>
> 1776   Patie's Wedding in D. Herd Anc. & Mod. Sc. Songs II. 191
> *When that the carles grew nappy, They danc'd as weel as they dow'd.*
>
> 1814   Spaniards iv. i, in New Brit. Theatre III. 234   *When that the
> crown..shall bind the brows Of my unnatural brother.*
>
> *1883   F. Kemble Poems 38   White was their snowy vesture, And shining as the Alps, when that the sun Gems their pale robes with
> diamonds.*
>
> 1999   in M. B. Montgomery & J. S. Hall Dict. Smoky Mountain Eng.
> (2004) 649   *I can see why that that would be so.*

Comment: A good reason not  to go to dictionaries for syntactic information. It doesn't have anything to do with "adding" anything to anything. It's all movement.